# getting the value to the Entry using tkinter

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

I want to know how to display the values using Entry? i mean for instance if i have a function like:

```
def open():
    path=tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Image File",'.jpg')])
    blue, green, red = cv2.split(path)
    total = path.size
    B = sum(blue) / total
    G = sum(green) / total
    R = sum(red) / total
    B_mean1.append(B)
    G_mean1.append(G)
    R_mean1.append(R)

    blue.set(B_mean1)
    green.set(G_mean1)
    red.set(R_mean1)

root = Tk()

blue_label = Label(app,text = 'Blue Mean')
blue_label.place(x = 850,y = 140)
blue = IntVar(None)
blue_text = Entry(app,textvariable = blue)
blue_text.place(x = 1000,y = 140)

green_label = Label(app,text = 'Green Mean')
green_label.place(x = 850,y = 170)
green = IntVar(None)
green_text = Entry(app,textvariable = green)
green_text.place(x = 1000,y = 170)

red_label = Label(app,text = 'Red Mean')
red_label.place(x = 850,y = 200)
red = IntVar(None)
red_text = Entry(app,textvariable = red)
red_text.place(x = 1000,y = 200) 

button = Button(app, text='Select an Image',command = open)
button.pack(padx = 1, pady = 1,anchor='ne')
button.place( x = 650, y = 60)

root.mainloop()
```

I have specified all the necessary imports and list variables. Still the value is not being displayed in the Entry field.

like if i get the value as :
    blue mean = 37, 
    green mean = 36, 
    red mean = 41

and it will print in the console but not in the window. How can I achieve this?

Any suggestions are welcome!
Thanks for your supports!

Comment: `StringVar()` instead of `IntVar()`?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I want to recommend that instead of using the `place` method you use the `grid` method. It is a lot faster and allows you to do things in a much more orderly fashion - especially in this application. Note that there are other geometry managers - like `pack` - which are good in yet other instances. Anyways, your GUI:

```
root = Tk()

blue_label = Label(root, text="Blue mean:")
blue_label.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="w")
blue_entry = Entry(root)
blue_entry.grid(row=1, column=2)

green_label = Label(root, text="Green mean:")
green_label.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="w")
green_entry = Entry(root)
green_entry.grid(row=2, column=2)

red_label = Label(root, text="Red mean:")
red_label.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky="w")
red_entry = Entry(root)
red_entry.grid(row=3, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

That makes your GUI display nicely and without the manual geometry. Note that sticky just sets how the text is justified ("w" means west, and so the text justifies left).

**Now, for actually displaying the text, all you have to do is:**

```
blue_entry.insert(0, "blue-mean-value")
green_entry.insert(0, "green-mean-value")
red_entry.insert(0, "red-mean-value")
```

And if you are overwriting any text that is already there just do:

```
blue_entry.delete(0, END) # And green_entry and red_entry
```